# Cancelling a graph join from a graph homomorphism

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given (finite, simple) graphs $G$, $H$ and $K$ and a [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism)
$$
G+K\to H+K
$$
where $+$ denotes the [join](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphJoin.html), does it follow that there also exists a graph homomorphism $G\to H$?

If this is known, I'd also appreciate a reference.

Comment: Worth pointing out: we have (the inequality $\leq$ follows by retaining optimal colorings, while the inequality $\geq$ follows because if $\chi(G+K) < \chi(G) + \chi(K)$, then choose any such hypothetical coloring and notice that one of the two summands then would be colored with less colors than its chromatic number allows, which is impossible) the equality $\chi(G+K) = \chi(G) + \chi(K)$. Moreover, in general, if $X\to Y$, then $\chi(X)\leq\chi(Y)$. We now put this together. If $G+K\to H+K$, then $\chi(G)+\chi(K) = \chi(G+K)\leq\chi(H+K)=\chi(H)+\chi(K)$, hence $\chi(G)\leq\chi(H)$. So [..]

Comment: [..] we have proved that if $G+K\to H+K$, then $\chi(G)\leq \chi(H)$, hence $G\to K^{{\Large\chi(H)}}$. It follows that: *if* there is a counterexample to the implication you are asking about, *then* $H$ must be **non-complete**. Have you searched around among small such instances?

Comment: @PeterHeinig: Good point about the chromatic numbers. I guess the same applies to the clique numbers, i.e. $\omega(G)\leq\omega(H)$, so that $G\to H$ also follows when $G$ is complete. So far, I haven't done much of a search on small instances.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Sure. I was assuming that finiteness would be clear from the context, but I'll make it explicit in the question.

Comment: To repeat a comment to a deleted answer. The case of $K$ complete is in fact much easier, since the vertices of $K$ in both $G+K$ and $H+K$ are dominating (=connected to everyone elde). Since the image of a dominating vertex cannot be anyone else's image, and all dominating vertices can be permuted via automorphisms, we may simply assume that the vertices of $K$, and only them, are mapped to the vertices of $K$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: thanks for pointing out. While it is probably not my deleted answer that you are commenting on, your comment applies to it, too (since I erroneously used $K=K^1$). For those who still can read the deleted answer: this happened because for irrelevant reasons I was holding the (erroneous) belief 'all wheel graphs are perfect' (which is evidently false for odd-spoked wheels since the peripheral circuit constitutes an 'odd hole'), and then started to 'synthetically reason' with this erroneous belief. (The three-spoke wheel btw is indeed exceptional in that it has clique number 4).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $|K|=\infty$, then this is false, as a counterexample $G=K_2$, $H=K_1$, $K=K_\infty$ shows.

Let us prove that the claim is true if $K$ is finite (with no such assumption for $G$ and $H$). Induction on $|K|$; if $|K|=0$, the claim is trivial.

For the inductive step, consider a homomorphism $\psi\colon G+K\to H+K$. Set $G_1=\psi(G)\cap K$, $K_1=\psi(K)\cap K$, $H_1=\psi(K)\cap H$. If $G_1=\varnothing$, then $\psi\big|_G$ is a required homomorphism $G\to H$. So now we assume that $|G_1|>0$.

Each vertex of $G_1$ is connected with each of $K_1$ since $\psi$ is a homomorphism (thus in particulat $|K_1|<|K|$). Each vertex of $H_1$ is connected with each of $K_1$ by the definition of join. Thus, the induced subgraphs on $G_1\cup K_1(\subseteq K)$ and $H_1\cup K_1$ are isomorphic to $G_1+K_1$ and $H_1+K_1$, respectively. So $\psi\big|_{G_1\cup K_1}$ provides a homomorphism $G_1+K_1\to H_1+K_1$ which by the induction hypothesis implies the existence of a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G_1\to H_1$.

Finally, set $M=\psi(G)\cap H$. Each vertex of $M$ is connected with each of $K_1$, since $\psi$ is a homomorphism. Thus the map $\eta\colon G\to H$, 
$$
  \eta(g)=\begin{cases}
    \psi(g), &\psi(g)\in M;\\
    \varphi(\psi(g)), &\psi(g)\in G_1
  \end{cases}
$$
is a sought homomorphism. The step is proved.

Comment: This perfectly answers the question. I'd still be grateful for pointers to the literature where a proof may already have appeared.